# Netty - writeAndFlush and message ordering

Tags: java, netty, actor

I'm trying to implement distributed actor model which uses Netty as communication protocol - the NIO version with TCP connections.

Lets say we have 2 nodes (machines), each have Netty's server instances that pass the incoming messages to actors on that node. 
I would like to keep message ordering per same pair of remote actors, so my solution was to use asynchronous writeAndFlush method to send messages to remote node and actor - when another message needs to be sent to the same actor before the first one was delivered, I would add it to buffer and with the callback of the writeAndFlush message, process the next one from buffer. It looks like this:

```
   channel.writeAndFlush(message).addListener(new MessageListener(mailboxOfSelector));
```

the callback method is:

```
    @Override
    public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {

        Queue<RemoteMessage> unsentToMailbox = unsentMessages.get(mailboxOfSelector);

        if (!unsentToMailbox.isEmpty()) {
            RemoteMessage message = unsentToMailbox.poll();
            channel.writeAndFlush(message).addListener(this);
        }
    }
```

So if A and B are 2 server instances connected with Channel and we send from A -> B - my question would be: what does isSuccess flag mean in depth? and when does the callback actually return?

Does it return when it finished with last handler on A or actually when it is delivered to the first handler on the B?

Answer (score 0):

In `Netty5. Version alpha2`. after flush the data to socketchannel,Netty then callback the operationComplete method .In this case, it dose not means the data reach the client. It means the data has been sent to the TCP protocol stack.You can see these in source code:

```
io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.java
```

It will calls the `promise.trySuccess()` from the `remove()` method or `remove(Cause cause)`, witch can trigger the `operationComplete()` method.